# Using backticks around field names

Tags: mysql, backticks

After reading a couple of answers and comments on some SQL questions here, and also hearing that a friend of mine works at a place which has a policy which bans them, I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with using backticks around field names in MySQL.

That is:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `anotherfield` ...
-- vs --
SELECT id, name, anotherfield ...
```

Comment: backticks are really handy if you want to have column names like `count`, `type`, `table` or similar

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Comment: @knittl I think the question is, _should_ you have column names like `count`, `type`, and `table`. Those are awfully ambiguous terms and in almost every case those names could be improved to be more specific. Naming your columns things like that is also dangerous and a potential source of errors, as you never know when someone might forget to add the backticks or not realize they have to. I think it's better practice to just avoid using reserved terms as column names.

Comment: I use them always and so I am not running in danger having used reserved keywords at any time.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Using backticks permits you to use alternative characters. In query writing it's not such a problem, but if one assumes you can just use backticks, I would assume it lets you get away with ridiculous stuff like

```
SELECT `id`, `my name`, `another field` , `field,with,comma`
```

Which does of course generate badly named tables.

If you're just being concise I don't see a problem with it, 
you'll note if you run your query as such

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED Select foo,bar,baz
```

The generated warning that comes back will have back-ticks **and** fully qualified table names. So if you're using query generation features and automated re-writing of queries, backticks would make anything parsing your code less confused.

I think however, instead of mandating whether or not you can use backticks, they should have a standard for names. It solves more 'real' problems.

Comment: Do we need to use them in PostgreSQL also?

Comment: There's no need, only recommendation. It is useful to represent them quoted to avoid ambiguity with SQL keywords if in future, an SQL keyword is added that shares your fields name.

The only time you /need/ to quote is when a field _does_ share a keyword name, for instance, `select count from foo` vs `select "count" from foo` will give very different results.

But postgres differs from mysql in 2 ways: 1. Fields are quoted by `""`. 2. Unquoted fields are case insensitive http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 58):

The only problem with backticks is that they are not ANSI-SQL compliant, e.g. they don't work in SQL Server.

If there is a chance you would have to port your SQL to another database, use double quotes.

Comment: Yep. Use MySQL's ANSI mode - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html - to enable double-quotes in MySQL and thus regain cross-database compatibility. Backticks/quotes are also necessary because you never know what's going to become a reserved word in future DBMS versions.

Comment: That's very true! One of our server applications was running fine until we applied an upgrade to our database engine, which added a new keyword. Suddenly everything that queried a particular table broke.

Comment: @bobince When I was *new* to dev, I named a column `range` or something like that. When we upgraded to MySQL 5 it failed because it was a new reserved word!

Comment: Do not use double quotes.  It will not always work.  For instance...  DELETE FROM `app_key_stores` WHERE ("key" = 'c5cc4f30-31f3-0130-505e-14dae9da9fc5_range');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

DELETE FROM `app_key_stores` WHERE (`key` = 'c5cc4f30-31f3-0130-505e-14dae9da9fc5_range');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 46):

To me it makes a lot of sense to use them at all times when dealing with field names.

- Firstly, once you get into the habit, it doesn't hurt to just hit the backtick key.
- Secondly, to me, it makes it easier to see what exactly are the fields in your query, and what are keywords or methods.
- Lastly, it allows you to use whatever field name you wish when designing your table. Sometimes it makes a lot of sense to name a field "key", "order", or "values"... all of which require backticks when referring to them.

Comment: You should also add that it protects you from any future reserved words being used (which has bitten me before).

Comment: I actually had someone edit the extra backticks out of one of my question once, which upset me, since this reason is the exact reason I surround every variable with them

Comment: It also allows for safe use of non English labels, which alone is enough to encourage the use of backticks.

Answer (score 28):

Backticks aren't part of standard ANSI SQL.  From [the mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is
>   enabled, it is also allowable to quote
>   identifiers within double quotes

So if you use backticks and then decide to move away from MySQL, you have a problem (although you probably have a lot bigger problems as well)

Answer (score 9):

There isn't anything wrong if you keep using MYSQL, except maybe the visual fuziness of the queries. But they do allow the use of reserved keywords or embedded spaces as table and column names. This is a no-no with most database engines and will prevent any migration at a later time.

As for easy reading, many people use caps for SQL keywords, eg.

```
SELECT some_fied, some_other_field FROM whatever WHERE id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you ask to me, backticks should always be used. But there are some reasons why a team may prefer not to use them.

Advantages:

- Using them, there are no reserved words or forbidden chars.
- In some cases, you get more descriptive error messages.
- If you avoid bad practices you don't care, but... in real word, sometimes they are a decent way to avoid SQL injections.

Disadvantages:

- They are not standard and usually not portable. However, as long as you don't use a backtick as part of an identifier (which is the worst practice I am able to imagine), you can port your query by automatically removing backticks.
- If some of your query come from Access, they may quote table names with " (and maybe you can't remove all the " blindly). However, mixtures of backticks and double quotes are allowed.
- Some stupid software or function filters your queries, and has problems with backticks. However, they are part of ASCII so this means that your software/function is very bad.

Comment: Using backticks has absolutely nothing to do with avoiding SQL injections.

Comment: @andy it **might** help, since an attacker has to close it with another backtick to inject. It does little, but that's still something

Answer (score 4):

It's a lot easier to search your code-base for something in backticks. Say you have a table named `event`. `grep -r "event" *` might return hundreds of results. `` grep -r "\`event\`" * `` will return anything probably referencing your database.

Comment: In general it's not really a benefit. The tables one professionally comes across are named more like new_users_info than "general".

Answer (score 3):

Well, as far as I know, the whole purpose of using backticks is so you can use names that coincide with reserved keywords. So, if the name isn't colliding with a reserved keyword, I don't see any reason to use backticks. But, that's no reason to ban them, either.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Thing about backtick **``** is use for denote identifier like database_name, table_name etc, and single quote **''**, double quote **""** for string literals, whereas "" use for print value as it is and '' print the value variable hold or in another case print the text his have.

```
i.e 1.-> use `model`;   
    here `model` is database name not conflict with reserve keyword 'model'
2- $age = 27;
insert into `tbl_people`(`name`,`age`,`address`) values ('Ashoka','$age',"Delhi");

here i used both quote for all type of requirement. If anything not clear let me know..
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using some field names as default mysql or mssql values for example "status", you have to use backticks ( "select `status` from table_name" or "select id from table_name where `status`=1" ).
because mysql returns errors or doesnt work the query.

Answer (score -3):

The main use of backticks (`) in SQL is to use them in situations where you are going to call them again in upcoming clauses. In every other time it is recommended to use double quotes("").

For example

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' in ', city, ', ', statecode) AS `Publisher and Location`,
    COUNT(ISBN) AS "# Books",
    MAX(LENGTH(title)) AS "Longest Title",
    MIN(LENGTH(title)) AS "Shortest Title"
FROM Publisher JOIN Book
ON Publisher.PublisherID = Book.PublisherID WHERE INSTR(name, 'read')>0
GROUP BY `Publisher and Location`
HAVING COUNT(ISBN) > 1;
```

In the above statement do you see how `Publisher and Location` is used again in `GROUP BY` clause.

Instead of using

> GROUP BY  Name, city, statecode

I just used

> GROUP BY `Publisher and Location`

Only when such situations arise, it is useful to use backticks. In all other times using double quotes is recommended.