# mysql select syntax

Tags: mysql

What is the purpose of this symbol in MySQL queries?

```
`
```

For example:

```
SELECT `show` FROM table WHERE id = "4"
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/261455/492364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL the backtick is used to quote column names. It is normally optional but here it is needed because `SHOW` is a reserved word.

A list of reserved words can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between quotation marks (' and ") and backticks (`) in mysql.

Backticks are known as an "identifier quote" and are used to surround identifiers, such as:

tables
columns
indexes
stored functions
etc.

Quote go around strings, often used when inserting, updating, or trying to match against a string in the database (eg a WHERE clause)

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are known as an "identifier quote" and are used to surround identifiers, such as: you can live without them but but they are necessary when

- identifiers name contains spaces e.g. a column name is `` `customer name ``  `
- identifiers  name is a reserved work e.g. a column name is  `` `name `` `