# Unknown column 'Date' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
select * from invoice WHERE Date >= '$date' AND status='$status'
```

It returns an error:

```
Unknown column 'Date' in 'where clause'
```

I am not too good in PHP or MYSQL, but I dont see anything wrong. There is probably everything wrong though. I need assistance!

EDIT:

```
$var = $_GET['date1_year'] ."-" . $_GET['date1_month'] ."-" . $_GET['date1_day'];
$query = "select * from invoice WHERE DateOfCreation >= '$var' AND status='$status'";
```

And ofcourse it is logged in(authenticated) and is being executed with no errors, but no proper result either. My DateOfCreation is a DATE type and there are actually the $_GET variables. I want it to search for all records before $var.

Comment: Is there a `Date` column in the table...? Can it be spelled `date` instead of `Date`? More info please. If it isn't a spelling/table not having column then I can think of perhaps a conflict with a Date function..

Comment: As a begginer, I assumed this would search for when the record was created and not a "date" Column.

Comment: You may want to look at [surrounding your column name in backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names) just to avoid any data-type collisions.

Comment: If your using Linux based MySql, the columns are case sensitive i belive, on windows it does not matter, does your column start with an upper case ?

Comment: It is not a column, I thought date is when the record is created or is there something else?

Comment: No. You are referencing a column. You can use the Mysql date function if you need it, though.

Comment: @Brad Christie, does the `'` single quotes not have the same effect as the backticks?

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe: No, if you want the date the row was created you'll need to create a column for it.  Date reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: How would I use the Mysql Date Function in my code?

Comment: @RobertPitt: Don't think so, single quotes are for strings.

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe: That depends on what you need to do with it.

Comment: Ok, Now I have a Column named DateOfCreation and a Variable called $date I want the query to search for all records which are before $date.

Comment: DateOfCreation obviously contains when it the row was created in a VarChar which has "19-01-2011" inside of it

Comment: Don't use VarChar. Use the date type. That way you can manipulate it better and do comparisons. If you MUST use varchar, at least sort your date like YYYY-MM-DD so that you can do < and > easier.

Comment: DateOfCreation should be a DATE or DATETIME type. Your comparison won't work as expected otherwise.

Comment: mno4k and Bob Baddeley, I have changed it to Date and edited it properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not search for before $date. I will edit my question to show what my code is.

Comment: Why is noone answering my post? I need urgent help here :(

Comment: Doesnt matter, I just had my variables set incorrectly. It is now working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from invoice WHERE DateOfCreation >= '$date' AND status='$status'
```

While it would work, I encourage you to look into parameterized queries in order to prevent SQL injection attacks. See here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

> for all records before $var

So you mean this then? (changed >= to <)

```
$var = $_GET['date1_year'] ."-" . $_GET['date1_month'] ."-" . $_GET['date1_day'];
$query = "select * from invoice WHERE DateOfCreation < '$var' AND status='$status'";
```

With your EDIT, I assume this error is gone?

> Unknown column 'Date' in 'where
>   clause'