# MYSQL - Quoted table / field names vs unquoted names

Tags: mysql, syntax

I basically always leave row and table names unquoted in my MYSQL queries - it's never caused me a problem, and I find it more readable.  However, I have noticed that some people keep them enclosed in backticks.

So, what's the difference between a quoted table name and an unquoted?  Any advantages / disadvantages?  Are there situations where you might need to enclose a name in quotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using backticks around field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An identifier (such as a table, index, column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, and other object names) may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it. (reference [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html))

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it in the other topic very quick: I've seen a database that had a field named "order". Now you'll get a syntax error if you use that without backticks, as it is a reserved word (as in `ORDER BY` )