# mySQL php, code conflict

Tags: php, mysql

```
$check = mysql_query("
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE username = '$usercheck'
");
```

Above is my code, the problem I have is I can't create the table `stonecrg_password.users` because of the period.

How can I change the code above so that it'll only show `stonecrg_users`. Even if I change the code to:

```
$check = mysql_query("
SELECT username 
FROM stonecrg_users 
WHERE username = '$usercheck'
");
```

It will still show `stonecrg_password.stonecrg_users`.

Comment: if i understand you, I will die immediately :P

Comment: Is `stonecrg_password` a database, or is it supposed to be a table in a database?

Comment: And what did Dreamweaver have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear for me, but as far as I know you can use ` to mark tables, columns and database in a mysql query. For instance:

```
SELECT `<tablename>`.`<columnname>`
FROM `<dbname>`.`<tablename>`
WHERE `<tablename>`.`<columnname>` = '$usercheck'
```

And if your problem is Database selection, then use following before query.

```
//$connection is your connection handler
mysql_select_db('<dbname>',$connection);
```

Comment: [Backticks (**`**)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names) are typically used like that, but I don't see how that can solve the problem the OP is describing. The second part, though, I suspect may have something to do with it.

Comment: True! I guess we need to wait till the user provides clarity

Comment: Also, I think if you put `tablename`s on each field in the `SELECT` statement, MySQL will complain/fail. You only need it for disambiguation, I believe.

Comment: stonecrg_password is a database. My question is how can I fix the code so that it doesnt ask for a table named 'stonecrg_password.user' and i can just use 'stonecrg_user'  Because at the moment i dont have the db  'stonecrg_password.user' created, because of the period in there i cant create it so how can i change it so it would instead ask for 'stonecrg_user'

Comment: From what I understand stonecrg_user is a table name. what is the database name in which stonecrg_user table is created?

Comment: Go here, http://stonecraftserver.com/Untitled-3.php type anything for username and password, so it returns the error "Table 'stonecrg_password.user' doesn't exist" I cant create that table because it has a period after password, so my question is how can I change the code above, so instead of asking for the table with .user it would just be 'stonecrg_user'

Comment: it would be great if you can post here the connection string and a line of your query together to get the idea

Comment: How could I get that lol? Simplify it for me? im pretty new at this

Comment: well if you are new and you dont mind sharing, Share the code of stonecraftserver.com/Untitled-3.php here.