# Mysql UPDATE error, why

Tags: php, mysql

I have this part of code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
$rec = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());
$like = $rec['like'];
$like += 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET like = '$like' WHERE id = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
```

and returning this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like = '1' WHERE id = '43'' at line 1"

Comment: PHP's `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` family) is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Please use [something else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIKE` is a reserved MySQL keyword. Quote your column names to avoid mistaking them for keywords:

```
... SET `like` = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a reserved keyword `LIKE`

try it like this:

```
"UPDATE `posts` SET `like` = '$like' WHERE `id` = '$id'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that like is a mysql keyword, either change the column name in your database or surround with backticks.

Also dont use mysql_ functions use mysqli or PDO as what you have is not safe and outmoded

Answer (score 0):

"like" is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), it is not recommended to use it to name columns. If it is not possible for you to rename the column, modify your UPDATE statement by escaping it with [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names) :

```
`like`
```