# PHP not inserting into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently having difficulty understanding why the following script returns success back to the browser but doesn't actually insert the data into the database.
I know I am using the old MySQL instructions but I doubt this should be creating this problem.
Thanks in Advance Alistair

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="XXXXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXXXXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="XXXXXXXXXX"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define Variables
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$password1=$_POST['password1']; 
$password2=$_POST['password2']; 
$emailadd=$_POST['emailadd']; 

if($password1==$password2){
    //Ecnrypt Password Using SHA512
    $password1 = hash("sha512", $password1);
}

else {
    //Passwords don't match return user to form with parameter
    header("location:adduser.php?pwnomatch");
}

//Check user doesn't already exist
$sqlcheckuser="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$result1=mysql_query($sqlcheckuser);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

//If user exists redirect back to login form
if($count==1){
    header("location:adduser.php?userexist");
}

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($myusername);
$password1 = stripslashes($mypassword);
$emailadd = stripslashes($emailladd);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$emailadd = mysql_real_escape_string($emailladd);
$sqlinsertuser="INSERT INTO $tbl_name ('username', 'password', 'emailaddress' VALUES ($username, $password1, $emailadd)";
mysql_query($sqlinsertuser);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result2);

// Register user then redirect to "viewuser.php" with success parameter
header("location:viewuser.php?success");

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: SQL Injections, here I come. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name ('username', 'password', 'emailaddress' VALUES ($username, $password1, $emailadd)
```

You have no closed your bracket on the column names. So your query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name (`username`, `password`, `emailaddress`) VALUES ($username, $password1, $emailadd)
```

Something I did not notice in my original post; You have used quotes instead of backticks.

Quotes in queries normally represent a string, backticks are explained here:

[Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I had, it would be because inverted commas are not backticks

Comment: Of course, inverted commas are still useful where strings are concerned, but with +4 votes to your name, who cares? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of errors in your query string. It should be

```
$sqlinsertuser="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (`username`, `password`, `emailaddress` )
        VALUES( '$myusername', '$mypassword', '$emailadd' )";
```

---

Notice the use of backticks instead of apostrophe for passing the field names. And usage of the quote marks instead inside **`VALUES`**.

---

You are using wrong variables inside the query.