# my PHP code will NOT insert records into my SQL dabase table

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code/file on my website but for some ungodly reason it will not insert the records typed in by the user into the mySQL database table as it is required to. Can anyone tell me why this is?

So far as I can tell the code is completely correct I don't know why this is happening...

Please help...Code is below...

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
<form action="register_development_file_1.php" method="post">
    Email:  <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    Date:   <input type="text" name="date"><br />
    Time:   <input type="text" name="time"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

    <?php
    if  (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
        if (!$con)
        {
            die("Could not connect to the database: " . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("wwwbrecs_BREC",$con);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO 'signups' ('signup_email_address', 'signup_date', 'signup_time') VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]')";

        mysql_query($sql,$con);

        mysql_close($con);
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` after the query statement to check for errors. Furthermore, `mysql_x` functions are deprecated. Have a look at PDO and mysqli as a replacement.

Comment: I'm sorry my php skills are poor. What exactly is a commit?

Answer (score 2):

There is a **syntax** error in your query, you sholdn't surround table name and column with quotes `'` , at least you can use backtick `

```
INSERT INTO 'signups' ('signup_email_address', 'signup_date','signup_time')
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup _time) VALUES
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO `signups` (`signup_email_address`, `signup_date`, `signup _time`) VALUES
```

Only values (actually not integers for integers columns) should be surrounded with quotes `'`.

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and indeed you are at risk of `sql injection`, have a look here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should use prepared statment to avoid any risk

Answer (score 0):

Here, is a  better-version of script you created, because yours was 100% open to SQL injections, and really not even a conventional way of codding, this is safer but if you need safe, then I suggest you learn about PDO from **[here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)**

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db("wwwbrecs_BREC", $con) or die(mysql_query());

      $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
      $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date'])
      $time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time'])

       $sql = "INSERT INTO 
            signups ('signup_email_address', 'signup_date','signup_time') 
            VALUES  ('".$email."','".$date."','".$time."')";

        mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_close($con);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

signups table should not be surrounded by single quotes ' but apostrophes `

Therefore

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'signups' ('signup_email_address', 'signup_date',                          'signup_time') VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]')";
```

Should be

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `signups` ('signup_email_address', 'signup_date',                          'signup_time') VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]')";
```

Comment: you shouldn't use backticks at all

Comment: Why not? Here I have found a good explanation why they can be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Comment: Well it is not always up to you to design the database.

Comment: Hello everyone I tried the following code as was suggested above

Comment: <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_mysql);
       mysql_select_db("wwwbrecs_BREC", $con) or die(mysql_query());

      $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
      $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
      $time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time']);

       $sql = "INSERT INTO 
            signups ('signup_email_address', 'signup_date','signup_time') 
            VALUES  ('".$email."','".$date."','".$time."')";

        mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: but I got these 2 errors

Comment: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/wwwbrecs/public_html/register_development_file_1b.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_query() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/wwwbrecs/public_html/register_development_file_1b.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO signups 
    (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time) 
    VALUES 
    ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time']) . "')";
```

this should do the trick, also check your security