# MySQL Order by boolean value tinyint

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, innodb

I am using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64).

This query fails with a `You have an error in your SQL syntax[...]near 'read ASC'` message :

```
SELECT 'messages'.* FROM 'messages' WHERE 'messages'.'user_id' = 2 ORDER BY read ASC;
```

where the `read` column is a `TINYINT(1)` value generated by the Rails ActiveRecord interface to store boolean values.

The same action works when switching to postgresql, but i currently have no access to the pg generated queries.
  Is there something wrong with the actual query? (maybe i cannot order by a tinyint) or should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read is reserve keyword in mysql 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

you have to add 'read' ASC in your query

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [naveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001703/866022), you'll need to [change your single quotation marks into backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261476/190597):

```
SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`user_id` = 2 ORDER BY read ASC;
```

Better yet, do not use MySQL reserved words as column names. To change the name, use `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE messages CHANGE read seen TINYINT
```

Comment: The actual code uses backticks, it was a typo. Thanks for the 'seen' suggestion i was actually stuck trying to find a good renaming!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is "read" is a keyword in mysql. It is better if you can avoid using reserved words for column identifiers

You can use it with backticks,

```
ORDER BY `read' ASC
```