# Insert Query not working

Tags: mysql

I have applied a insert query but its giving error .

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `registration`(`Activation`) VALUES('".$activation."') WHERE email= '". trim($_POST['email']) ."'");
```

Comment: `INSERT`'s don't have a `WHERE` clause. Did you mean to use an `UPDATE`?

Comment: What's the error say, Did you run mysql_connect first, and select a database? Also you should look into other methods of connecting to a sql database. As mysql_ functions are depreciated.

Comment: Actually i am going to take the value from the session .thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use update statement instead of INSERT to use where clause

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("UPDATE `registration` 
                    SET `Activation` = '".$activation." 
                    WHERE email= '". trim($_POST['email']) ."'"
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want just update a column in table so you need an `UPDATE` not `INSERT` .

and also you should sanitize you POST variable to prevent sql injection.

```
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])) ;

  $registerquery = mysql_query("UPDATE `registration` 
                              SET `Activation` '".$activation."'
                              WHERE email= '". trim($email) ."'");
```

- Please move to PDO or mysqli as mysql is already deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to overwrite an existing value **use an UPDATE statement** and not an INSERT statement this is the reason why it is not working. INSERT works when you are trying to insert a new value there should not be a condition in it (where clause).

Answer (score 1):

check this `registration`(`Activation`) it does not seem correct, the ` should maybe be ' and maybe you should start the query with @ in order to avoid sql injection attack

Comment: Back ticks (`) are allowed in mysql, are used to denote field names, So should not be used around `registration`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names