# Trying to create a memory table in mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql, memory-table

I am trying to create a memory table in mysql through php but i keep getting an error:

```
Error creating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order INT)ENGINE = INNODB' at line 1
```

Below is the code that i am using to try and create it:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons(FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT, Order INT)ENGINE = MEMORY";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Database my_db created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are escaping the predefined constants in MySQL like **'order'**

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `Persons`(`FirstName` CHAR(30),`LastName` CHAR(30),`Age` INT, `Order` INT)ENGINE = MEMORY";
```

See this post for more clarification:

[Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Comment: Please mark it as the answer, so people know it's closed. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

`Order` is a r[eserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in sql, try replace it with other terminology.