# Query fails when getting data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from an database that I have created in phpMyAdmin. My problem is that however I change my query I'm getting the same type of error message using the `mysql_error()` function:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''foods'' at line 1

PHP code index file:

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';

$query = "SELECT 'food_type', 'calories' FROM 'foods'";

if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
        $food = $query_row('food_type');
        $calories = $query_row('calories');

        echo $food.' has '.$calories.' calories ';
    }
}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

PHP code database connection file:

```
<?php
$connectionError = 'Can\'t connect.';

$mySqlHost = 'localhost';
$mySqlUser = 'root';
$mySqlPassword = 'Bhu8Nji9';

$mySqlDataBase = 'my_first_database';

if(!@mysql_connect($mySqlHost, $mySqlUser, $mySqlPassword) || !@mysql_select_db($mySqlDataBase)){
    die($connectionError);
}else{
    //echo 'Connected';
}
?>
```

Comment: In your query, swap those apostrophes for backticks. Since none of them are reserved words, you can get away with removing them too.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your query *[Use Backticks instead of Single quotes]*

```
$query = "SELECT 'food_type', 'calories' FROM 'foods'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT `food_type`, `calories` FROM foods";
```

Comment: Or just SELECT food_type, calories FROM foods - and now change your password.

Comment: @Strawberry, Yes but it is always a good practice to enclose the columns under backticks.

Comment: It is good practice, but it's also incredibly irritating IMHO. A better idea is to avoid the use of reserved words.

Comment: @Strawberry, Exactly. +1

Answer (score 1):

use this..

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT food_type,calories FROM foods");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes around table name and field names.

```
$query = "SELECT food_type, calories FROM foods";
```

Also avoid mysql_* functions.

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Read following to know when or why to use backticks

[Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, added backticks in table foods

```
$query = "SELECT food_type, calories FROM `foods`";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem regarding of unknown column name
you should use backtick as:

```
$query = "SELECT `food_type`, `calories` FROM foods";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your query. It should be as below,

```
$query = "SELECT food_type, calories FROM `foods`";
```