# Play Framework SQL evolution script - error with integer column?

Tags: mysql, sql, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

I got the following error:

> We got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'integer not null, constraint pk_checkpoint
>   primary key (id))' at line 9 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000], while
>   trying to run this SQL script:

The generated SQL:

```
1 # --- Rev:1,Ups - 491c235

2

3 create table checkpoint (

4 id                        bigint auto_increment not null,

5 name                      varchar(80) not null,

6 longitude                 double not null,

7 latitude                  double not null,

8 points                    integer not null,

9 message                   varchar(160) not null,

10 scenario_id               bigint,

11 index                     integer not null,

12 constraint pk_checkpoint primary key (id))

13;
```

My model:

```
@Entity
public class Checkpoint extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public double longitude;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public double latitude;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public int points;

    @Column(length = 160, nullable = false)
    public String message;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CheckpointAnswer> possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<CheckpointAnswer>();

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Scenario scenario;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public int index;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: index is a reserved word, try changing it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above, and not to detract from the point that avoiding reserved words is probably a good idea, if you really wanted the column to be called index, you can manually create the table with MySQL workbench or your sql tool of choice using a backtick around the column name (`index`). In Scala/anorm at least, this doesn't change how you refer to the column in the source code. (For cross-database compatability, configuring MySQL to use double quotes rather than backticks would probably also be a good idea. Further discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names).)