# Rename a column named "add" in mysql

Tags: mysql, rename, alter

I never thought about the implication and I created a column named "add" in mysql. (obviously it was not in my mind while creating the table that add is a reserved word) While giving every query this is turning out to be a problem. I've decided to change the name and now I can't get to change it either.

I tried the following variations: none worked

```
mysql> alter table ml_n1 m modify column m.add addmovie tinyint(4);                                 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm modify column m.add addmovie tinyint(4)' at line 1

mysql> alter table ml_n1 modify column add addmovie tinyint(4);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add addmovie tinyint(4)' at line 1

mysql> alter table ml_n1 modify column 'add' 'addmovie tinyint(4)';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''add' 'addmovie tinyint(4)'' at line 1

mysql> alter table ml_n1 modify column 'add' addmovie tinyint(4);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''add' addmovie tinyint(4)' at line 1

mysql> alter table ml_n1 change add addmovie tinyint(4);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add addmovie tinyint(4)' at line 1

mysql> alter table ml_n1 change 'add' addmovie tinyint(4);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''add' addmovie tinyint(4)' at line 1
```

Could someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Try placeing backticks (`) around the column name

Comment: `add` is a reserved word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE ml_n1 CHANGE COLUMN `add` addmovie TINYINT(4)
```

As you have hinted at; calling a column `add` is problematic because `add` is a reserved word in MySQL, in order to reference the column you need to escape it with backticks, `.

You need `CHANGE` rather than `MODIFY` to change a column's name.

**N.B.** From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, column_definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column, other than index attributes such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE.

I wouldn't call this a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table ml_n1 change `add` addmovie tinyint(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you:

```
ALTER TABLE `ml_n1` CHANGE COLUMN `add` `addmovie` tinyint(4);
```

Back-ticks allow you to reference column names that contain reserved words or spaces etc.
I personally make it a habit to place backticks around table and column references when coding with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks around the column name

```
    mysql>alter table m1_n1 change `add` addmovie tinyint(4);
```