# Drodown option to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My query is not sending chosen state to database,

```
<?php

    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){

        session_start();
    }


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    // Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // escape variables for security
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
    $number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['number']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $addressone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['addressone']);
    $addresstwo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['addresstwo']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']); 
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['zip']);


    $sql="UPDATE users SET `firstname`='$firstname', `lastname` = '$lastname',`number`='$number', `email` = '$email',`addressone`='$addressone', `addresstwo` = '$addresstwo',`city`='$city', `state` = '$state', `zip` = '$zip' WHERE `id`='" .$_SESSION['id']."'";



    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {

      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    header("Location:dashboard.php");

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The part of this form is

```
<div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="state">State</label>

                <div class="col-md-1">

                    <select id="state" name="state" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $state; ?>">
                        <option value="1">Select</option>
                        <option value="2">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="3">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="4">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="5">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="6">California</option>
                        <option value="7">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="8">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="9">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="10">District of Colombia</option>
                        <option value="11">Florida</option>
                        <option value="12">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="13">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="14">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="15">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="16">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="17">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="18">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="19">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="20">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="21">Maine</option>
                        <option value="22">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="23">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="24">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="25">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="26">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="27">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="28">Montana</option>
                        <option value="29">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="30">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="31">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="32">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="33">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="34">New York</option>
                        <option value="35">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="36">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="37">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="38">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="39">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="40">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="41">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="42">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="43">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="44">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="45">Texas</option>
                        <option value="46">Utah</option>
                        <option value="47">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="48">Washington</option>
                        <option value="49">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="50">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="51">Wyoming</option>
                        <option value="52">American Samoa</option>
                        <option value="57">Federated States of Micronesia</option>
                        <option value="53">Guam</option>
                        <option value="58">Marshall Islands</option>
                        <option value="54">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                        <option value="55">Puerto Rico</option>
                        <option value="56">Virgin Islands</option>
                        <option value="59">Palau</option>
                        <option value="60">AA</option>
                        <option value="61">AE</option>
                        <option value="62">AP</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You dont need a value attribute on your select element

Comment: @DavidJones is right, this could also be the cause of your error.

Comment: and just making sure, is this select inside the form tags?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your query is wrong

This one

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET `firstname`='$firstname', `lastname` = '$lastname',`number`='$number', `email` = '$email',`addressone`='$addressone', `addresstwo` = '$addresstwo',`city`='$city', `state` = '$state', `zip` = '$zip' WHERE `id`='" .$_SESSION['id']."'";
```

**remove ``**

its should be like this

```
 $sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname', lastname = '$lastname',number='$number', email = '$email',addressone='$addressone', addresstwo= '$addresstwo',`city`='$city', state = '$state', zip = '$zip' WHERE id='" .$_SESSION['id']."'";
```

Comment: So that fixed, now another problem, the result is not displaying on the actual page. So if Georgia is picked, it sends to the databse but not echoing on the page itself

Comment: Back-ticks around the column name shouldn't have been the issue. See this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Comment: It did work but the result is not showing in the actual index.php page. It still shows as "select"

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 The goal of this form is to be able to save the data as well as send it to the database. It is in the database now after your help but not showing as saved.

Comment: Not sure how to accept, however, you did answer the original question no doubt.