# CakePHP: difference between backtick query and normal query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, backticks

I have 3 blog tables in my CakePHP application that are linked with a HABTM association following the CakePHP naming conventions: posts - post_tag_links - tags.

I try to get an array with all the posts that are linked to a specific tag (e.g. "design"). This query works for me:

```
$this->Post->query("
    SELECT
        Post.id, Post.title FROM posts AS Post
    LEFT JOIN
        post_tag_links AS PostTagLink ON Post.id = PostTagLink.post_id
    LEFT JOIN
        tags AS Tag ON Tag.id = PostTagLink.tag_id
    WHERE
        Tag.slug = 'design'
    GROUP BY
        Post.id"
);
```

CakePHP then generates the following query and gave me 4 results:

```
SELECT
    Post.id,
    Post.title 
FROM
    posts AS Post 
LEFT JOIN
    post_tag_links AS PostTagLink 
        ON Post.id = PostTagLink.post_id 
LEFT JOIN
    tags AS Tag 
        ON Tag.id = PostTagLink.tag_id 
WHERE
    Tag.slug = 'design' 
GROUP BY
    Post.id
```

BUT... to do some best practice, it's better to not use the "query" method. So I tried the "find all" method:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Post.id',
        'Post.title'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'post_tag_links',
            'alias' => 'PostTagLink',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Post.id' => 'PostTagLink.post_id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'tags',
            'alias' => 'Tag',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Tag.id' => 'PostTagLink.tag_id',
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Tag.slug' => 'design'
    ),
    'group' => 'Post.id'
    )
));
```

CakePHP then generates the following query and gave NO single result:

```
SELECT
    `Post`.`id`,
    `Post`.`title` 
FROM
    `kattenbelletjes`.`posts` AS `Post` 
LEFT JOIN
    `kattenbelletjes`.`post_tag_links` AS `PostTagLink` 
        ON (
            `Post`.`id` = 'PostTagLink.post_id'
        ) 
LEFT JOIN
    `kattenbelletjes`.`tags` AS `Tag` 
        ON (
            `Tag`.`id` = 'PostTagLink.tag_id'
        ) 
WHERE
    `Tag`.`slug` = 'design' 
GROUP BY
    `Post`.`id
```

After a lot of trial and error, I discovered the problem is the backticks that CakePHP creates when building up that last query.

My question is: what's the difference between the query with the backticks and the one without the backticks? And how can you leave those backticks in CakePHP?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backticks most probably aren't the problem, as all they do is escaping the identifiers. This is a pretty easy find btw.

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html**
- **[Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)**

The actual problem is more likely that you've defined the conditions in the wrong way, what you are doing there is creating string literal comparision conditions, ie

```
`Post`.`id` = 'PostTagLink.post_id'
```

Comparing the `id` column value to the string `PostTagLink.post_id` will of course fail.

The correct way to define identifier comparisons is to supply the conditon fragment as a single value instead of a key => value set, ie

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Post.id = PostTagLink.post_id'
)
```

and

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Tag.id = PostTagLink.tag_id'
)
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**

Comment: I'm glad you could help me so quickly because I was searching for it quite a long time. Thank you very much ndm!