# Insert fields into table dynamically but error with Query

Tags: php

```
public function add($table, $data, $exclude = array()){

$fields = $values = array();
if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude);
foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {

    if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
        $fields[] = "'$key'";
        $values[] = "'" . $this->db->real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";

    }
}

$fields = implode(",", $fields);
$values = implode(",", $values);

$query = "INSERT INTO $table($fields) VALUES ($values)";

 if(!$result = $this->db->query($query)) {
      echo "Prepare failed: (" . $this->db->errno . ") " . $this->db->error;
    }
```

}

Error

```
Prepare failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name','address','country','type','status') VALUES ('Starbucks','Washington ','U' at line 1

 $food->add("food", $_POST, "add");
```

Tested printing fields and values and they were correct. So called the function add and then got the error on syntax, but couldn't figure where query went wrong.

Comment: Post value of `print_r($fields)` and `print_r($values)` and quotes in column and table name create problem!!

Comment: I think your number of column fields do not match the number of corresponding values. From your error. ( 'name','address','country','type','status') VALUES ('Starbucks','Washington ','U')

Comment: @psyLogic and what about `quotes` in column name????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key should be wrapped in ` instead of '

```
$fields[] = "`$key`";
```

Comment: oh what does ` do?

Comment: @joe read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names