# SQL select like - containing only 1 word

Tags: sql, select

A SQL Table has a field with the name:

```
 image_colors
```

The value of this field can be a row of different colors - example:

```
green red blue white
```

When I search for a specific color, I use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `gallery_images` 
WHERE  `image_colors` LIKE  '%green%'
```

In this case, the value:

```
green red blue white
```

contains green and will be selected.

Question:

Is it possible with SQL to find only values with only 1 Word:

```
green
```

Comment: which RDBMS????

Comment: This seems like MySQL, is it?

Comment: So look for values that don't contain a space character? I'm assuming you're looking for more than just green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use simple equality comparison to select only values matching `green`:

```
select *
from gallery_images
where image_colors = 'green'
```

*Notes:*

- backticks are not necessary in your case and [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names) when not needed
- you should probably change your data model for many-to-many with `colors` dictionary table and junction table between `gallery_images` and `colors` to normalize your data and make lookups faster

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT * 
FROM  gallery_images 
WHERE  trim(image_colors)= 'green'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing query will work for single word also.  No need to do any change for single word value in search field.

But of course this query will degrade performance of your application.

Instead of storing multiple values in single column, it is better to create another table to store colors in form of Integer value as multiple rows.

Comment: OP needs to search for values containing only `green` word.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Like operator when you want records with only 'green' color.

```
select *
from gallery_images
where image_colors = 'green'
```