# i cant insert my data in to table in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The following query fails:

```
INSERT INTO education_details SET 
    candi_qualification ='BE,BSC',
    candi_uniboard = 'kce,kce',
    candiyop = '2015,2013',
    candi_grade_cgpa = 'b,b',
    candi_specilization = 'cse,cse',
    language = 'tamil,English',
    read = 'Yes,Yes',
    write = 'Yes,Yes',
    speak = 'Yes,Yes',
    candi_id = '1'
```

Error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read='Yes,Yes',write='Yes,Yes',speak='Yes,Yes',candi_id='1' 
> ' at line 1

Comment: show error like this   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read='Yes,Yes',write='Yes,Yes',speak='Yes,Yes',candi_id='1' <br>' at line 1

Comment: insert into education_details (candi_qualification,candi_uniboard,.....) values('value_to_candi_qualification ','value_to_candi_uniboard',.....)

Comment: your query is for update sir. not insert

Comment: the query used wont work.      try this for inserting http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp     and try this for updation http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: @Laxman palani Use Back quote use (\`)  instead of simple `read`. You have to Back quote use (\`) in all field. Try this.This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your column name exists in education_details table. Then there is one mistake which i am thinking is missing Back quote use (`).

Use Back quote use (`) instead of simple read. As i also mentioned above. This mat solve your issue.

```
 INSERT INTO education_details SET 
            `candi_qualification` ='BE,BSC',
            `candi_uniboard` = 'kce,kce',
            `candiyop` = '2015,2013',
           `candi_grade_cgpa` = 'b,b',
            `candi_specilization` = 'cse,cse',
            `language` = 'tamil,English',
            `read` = 'Yes,Yes',
            `write` = 'Yes,Yes',
            `speak` = 'Yes,Yes',
            `candi_id` = '1'
```

@Laxman palani you are using `read` and `write`. In which i may be wrong but as per mysql documentation its a `LOCK TYPE`. please read the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html .

By using **Back quote use (`)**. you may get rid of this.

Comment: Backticks or not, `INSERT INTO ... SET` will never work.

Comment: @roberto06 Can you please read the MySQL documentation before saying something that is not true?

Comment: @roberto06 Have you the mysql documentation. You can use the above query. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html] . If you read this link. you will know the fact. And also i am using this type of query for many years and its working fine.

Comment: Wow, you're right, just learned something. I was always taught `INSERT INTO` only works with `VALUES()`, my apologies.

Comment: @roberto06 Without knowing anything don't downgrade any one.

Comment: @roberto06 Now you know so can you remove your downgrade vote.

Comment: @Manish Ninja'd you to it ;)

Answer (score -2):

[Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

You need to use backticks around your column names (and around your table is also good practice).