# MYSQL join error. How to resolve?

Tags: mysql

MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `pet_info` LEFT JOIN `lostpets` ON `pet_info`.`id` = `lostpets`.`petid` LEFT JOIN `pet_images` ON `pet_info`.`id` = `pet_images`.`petid` LEFT JOIN ON `pet_info`.`pet_cat` CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 1 THEN `dog_breeds`.`id` WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 2 THEN `cat_breeds`.`id` END WHERE `pet_info`.`pet_user_id` = 581
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON `pet_info`.`pet_cat` CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 1 THEN `do' at line 7
```

Why error is appearing please help me. Gow can I resolve this error?

Comment: 'LEFT JOIN ON'. - Some basic formatting would probably help.

Comment: Can you please help me by writing answer.

Comment: No. There are too many errors.

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry it looks like you're missing an entire table name in there.  By the way, please kill those backticks, which makes it even harder to read your single line query.

Comment: Your problem may lie in the backticks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Comment: @Strawberry really too many errors in my query?

Comment: Yes. Too many..

Comment: Your final `LEFT JOIN` makes no sense because there is no table mentioned.  And there is a `CASE` expression there which might be out of place.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen value is always either 1 or 2

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use one join for two different tables. This is not possible. Format your query and explain, what you are trying to do.

Comment: if value = 1 then joining with dog breed table else joining with cat breed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formatted version of your query, highlighting some errors.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM pet_info p
  LEFT 
  JOIN lostpets l
    ON p.id = l.petid 
  LEFT 
  JOIN pet_images i
    ON p.id = i.petid 
  LEFT 
  JOIN  !! ERROR 1
    ON p.pet_cat !! ERROR 2
  CASE WHEN p.pet_cat = 1 
       THEN d.id !! ERROR 3
       WHEN p.pet_cat = 2 
       THEN c.id END !! ERROR 4
 WHERE p.pet_user_id = 581
```