# Snowflake query unable to display underscore in alias name

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I was writing a Snowflake query

```
select col1, col2 as col_2 from table;
```

In the resultant table, the alias 'col_2' comes as 'col 2', i.e without underscore. I know the questions is stupid but my poor googling skills gave no fruitful result.

Comment: use backticks to escape the space ``

Comment: I tried ..but the same result came. col-space-2, with the backticks around them:(

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Comment: Got it. Thanks a heap :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering for completeness. This "bug" appears to be fixed:

```
SELECT $2 as col_2
FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF100"."REGION"

## COL_2
## AFRICA
## AMERICA
## ASIA
## EUROPE
## MIDDLE EAST
```