# single quotes in row query (sequelize)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

code:

```
const query = `SELECT DISTINCT :attribute FROM "users"`

sequelize.query(query { replacements: { attribute: attributes[0] } });
```

result (generated by sequelize):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'locale' FROM "users"
```

how can i pass attribute to the query without single quotes or with double quotes ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Are you sure, that these quaracters are single quotes and not backticks ( ` )? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Comment: yeap, copied from console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholders like `:attribute` [represent query parameters](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html). You can't use them to build a dynamic query.

If you need to change which column you're looking at, you could set `query` to `SELECT DISTINCT ${attributes[0]} FROM "users"` instead, but definitely make sure that `attributes[0]` cannot contain user input or your code will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: couple of other solutions work but this one doesn't,
maybe cause it is array =_=