# Display only data from table using keyword entered in search box in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to filter out data from my table using a searchbox in HTML. My search box which should return value from SQL query.

But even if I search, the filtered table is not displayed.

I have checked the 'LIKE' query in phpMyAdmin with '%n' (which I meant an entry in my table ending with 'n' ) and it works, but since in mine I am searching for a specific text that is entered in the search box, I couldn't check for the query that I am using.

Would really appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

```
 <?php
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'zamil'; // Username
$db_pass = '1234'; // Password
$db_name = 'resi'; // Database Name
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}
else{
print("connected");
}
$output = '';
$query = '';

if (isset($_GET['search'])){

$searchq = $_GET['search'];

$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$query = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM 'salesflow' WHERE 'Rep Name' 
LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search!");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
$output = 'There was no entries';
}else{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $cname = $row['Source of Content'];
    $rname = $row['Rep Name'];

    $output .= '<div>'.cname.' '.rname.'</div>';
    }
  }
}

if ($query != 0) {
die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

?>

<form action="Sales1.php" method="post"> 
Search: <input type="text" name="search" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search" /><br />  
</form>

<?php print("$output"); ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you are using POST method of form, so instead of `$_GET['search']`  use `$_POST['search']`

Comment: "Could not search" is the answer that I got. Does that mean my query is wrong?

Comment: `"could not search!"` is a crappy error message. if you need to debug, then debug 101 is to use `mysqli_error()` -> `or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is incorrect:

```
SELECT * FROM 'salesflow' WHERE 'Rep Name' LIKE '%$searchq%'
```

You put single quotes (') around the `salesflow` table name and `Rep Name` column name but you should use backticks (`) instead.

For more information see [Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names).

Comment: $query = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM `salesflow` WHERE 
    `Rep Name` LIKE '".$searchq."'") or die("could not search!");
This is what I did, but its showing error in my SQL.

Comment: You're getting an error because that is not a valid SQL statement. You need backticks around the column name. You've also removed your wildcards, which will yield a different result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have entered a wrong query syntax.

```
$query = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM 'salesflow' WHERE
'Rep Name' LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search!");
```

It should be written like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM 'salesflow' WHERE
'Rep Name' LIKE '%".$searchq."%'") or die("could not search!");
```

Always use ' for string in query.

Also, my additional recommendation is not to use SQL for searching in the table, instead, use [DataTable based on AngularJS](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome).

Comment: umm, are you sure? why are you suggesting removing the wildcards? and are you aware that php can parse varibles inside double quotes. and no mention about `'salesflow'` and `'Rep Name'`. and ...

Comment: Uh sorry, forgot about the wildcards. Yes PHP can parse variable inside double quotes, but not SQL.

Comment: but you know that the php string is parsed before sending the query string, right? So those 2 query strings will result in the same exact output. all you are doing is making it a little more visible, but it doesn't make any difference.