# Is there a way to use a variable in a MySQL update query

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a form like this

```
<?php include 'file2.php' ; ?>
<form action="file1.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="LHS" value="column1">
   <input type="hidden" name="RHS" value="row">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I have an update query in `file2.php` like this

```
$lhs = $_POST['LHS']
$rhs = $_POST ['RHS']

$update = "UPDATE table1 SET
           column1 = '".$rhs."'
           WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";

mysqli_query($conn, $update);
```

So my questions is how can I use a variable($lhs) in place of "column1" to update mysql data

I have tried `$table1['column1']` method too, but it only seems to work on Rhs side but not the LHS

Comment: ` ".$lhs." ` = ' ".$rhs." '

Comment: Even hidden data on forms can be changed if the user wants, this will leave your code open to users being able to hack your web site.

Comment: Then what's a better way to do it @NigelRen ? I have only asked about it because I didn't want to have to create same file2.php over and over for different inputs with the same submit form pattern..

Comment: Adding dynamic column name from a form is not safe. One can easily edit that hidden name to say `id` and set whatever value they type. Try to use `PDO` for database. For whatever reason this is not safe.

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to achieve it's impossible to tell.  Do you really need to have dynamic statements like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most Importantly:** Your query is open to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn how to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2469308)

Also, it seems that the value of your `$lhs` variable is a [Reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). It is incidentally your column name as well. So, you [need to use backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261476/2469308) (`), asking MySQL to consider it as a column/table/database name or some aliased expression.

Now, just do the following, to use `$lhs` as a column in the Update query:

```
$update = "UPDATE table1 `" .
          $lhs . "` = '" . $rhs . "' 
          WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";

mysqli_query($conn, $update);
```

Comment: to add to this, PREPARE YOUR STATEMENTS.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I've already tried it. It doesn't work when I use the $lhs variable, but $rhs works fine.

Comment: @i0N77 what is the value of `$lhs` variable. I have just added backticks in the answer. Use them. Also ensure that a column name by value in the `$lhs` actually exists in your database.

Comment: Ah, it's working now. Just didn't know that we would have to use those backticks and all, will learn how to use prepared statements first and then include this in it. Upvoted.

Comment: @i0N77 Most likely in `$lhs`, there must be a reserved keyword (in MySQL), which is incidentally your column name as well. So MySQL throws errors, if you dont use backticks, asking MySQL to consider it as a column/table/database name or some aliased name.