# Do i need to use $stmt = $conn->prepare for this prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The current syntax for my prepared statements is incorrect, where I: (INSERT...?, ?, ?)

I have tried to copy syntax from different examples but it seems the more I try the more I break my login system.
I have somewhat conflicting examples and am not sure which syntax is the correct one to use. Do I need to use $stmt = $conn->prepare before INSERT?

```
// create preprepared statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

// check if sql statement is correct
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {

    // Add the variables to the stmt
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_hashed_password, $param_email);
    $param_username = $username;
    $param_password = $hashed_password;
    $param_email = $email;

    // Attempt to execute the stmt
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        // If statement executed
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        header("location: login.php");
```

At the moment it's not inserting any values into my db and user registration is failing.

EDIT:

$password = $_POST['password'];

$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

It has just occurred to me that this might be incorrect usage of password_hash?

Comment: `$param_hashed_passwor` != `$param_password`

Comment: U have ur parameters defined after your bind statement.

Comment: @user9189147 - it is fine to do so in `mysqli`

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out, however still getting the same error after fixing typo.

Comment: @JoeS. What is the error you get?

Comment: @Progman "User Registration Failed because of: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?)' at line 1"

Comment: @JoeS. `Password` is a MySQL reserved word. You might want to rename that column or use backticks, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Do i need to use "$stmt = $conn->prepare" for this prepared statement?` - in short, No! You must however use the `prepare` method to actually generate the `prepared statement`, it MUST be done before actually attempting to do the `INSERT` and it is wise to assign that to a variable so that you can fork the program logic dependant upon success/failure.

My preference is to do as below - use a `try/catch` block and use the return values or variables at various stages to determine whether to throw meaningful(?) exceptions to help debug - so as example you could do this

```
/*
    assumed that $username,$password & $email 
    are all defined and available at ths stage.

    also assumed that `session_start()` has 
    been called and that no html output occurs
    before this point ( unless using output buffering )
*/

try{
    # example

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` ( `username`, `password`, `email` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){
        /* if there were no problems continue with the database operations */
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $hash, $email );

        /* not sure how the hash was generated so just put this in to be sure... */
        $hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        if( $result ){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            exit( header( 'Location: login.php' ) );
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Bogus! There was some sort of problem...');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql query');
    }
}catch( Exception $e ){
    exit( $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to call session_start() before this code, considering it is only the register page?

Comment: because you call `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`