# Update query hangs my website when i want to update rows in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm facing an issue in updating rows in mysql table. I'm currently working on social media website. There's a notification table where we've all users notification.
For example
"**John liked your post, Sara commented on your post**" Just like this

Table structure is given below.

[image]

As you can see i have a column "**IsRead**". If the user click on "**Mark all as read button**"
a query executes.

```
UPDATE notification SET isRead = 1 WHERE toUser = $id
```

When i execute this query it takes about 2 minutes or above and at the end it says connection to server has been lost. Error snap is attached below

[image]

Please suggest me what's the right way to create a table for notification. My created table structure is given above.

This is my javascript code:

```
function markAsRead(){
$('.notifications-area').html('<li><center>Noting to display</center></li>');
$('.list-notification').html('<li><center>Noting to display</center></li>');
$('#countNotifications').html(0);
$('#countNotifications1').html(0);
$.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        method:'POST',
        url: "<?php echo site_url()?>/Main/markAsRead",
        datatype:"JSON",
        success:function(responce)
        {   
            
        },
        error:function(e)
        {
           console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function markAsRead(){
    
    $data=$this->m->markAsRead();
     echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function markAsRead(){
    $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
    $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE notification SET isRead = 1 WHERE toUser = $userid and isRead = 0");
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Share you code because, most likely, this is a bug in your code.

Comment: You don't need to update rows which are already read - so you can do `WHERE toUser = $id AND isRead = 0`

Comment: @Luuk Please check the code

Comment: You should  read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: How many records are in that table ?  Did you check that the value `$userid` is the correct id ?

Comment: The query looks okay. Is db-server is on same machine? 
2 tips: 
1. Add backticks to your query, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/261476/3710053. 
2. isRead seems to be a boolean. Try to use tinyint(1) for those.

Comment: @Luuk almost 15,000 entries in database