# Count for registered members PHP MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this code of mine.
I want to retrieve total counts of registered members for every event they registered in. I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as TotalAttendee 
from activities 
join projectcode on activities.projects_id = projectcode.projects_id
join participants on participants.act_id = activities.id
where activities.projects_id='1001' 
order by YEAR(activities.activity_date) desc
```

This is should be the output

```
+------------+----------------+
|Event Title |Total Attendees |
+------------+----------------+
|Event 1     | 110            |
+------------+----------------+
|Event 2     | 90             |
+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please show the sample data

Comment: It is in the example.

Comment: Yes I understand. But without knowing the source it is hard to help

Comment: I don't know how to insert an image here.

Comment: No image, test same as you added the expected result

Comment: I'll try to explain.
In my program, there are activity table and participant table. The output I want to achieve is if my how many participants in every activity.

Comment: As you have not included the DDL for your tables or sample data, it is not clear what the relationships are. Suspect you just need to add `group by activities.id` as `Event Title` is probably (?) functionally dependent on `activities.id`.

Comment: Please add the error you are getting or add the current response, also add an entity relationship diagram to know your data model

Answer (score 0):

From your question and the explanation in comments; I can understand;

> The output you want to achieve is how many participants in every
> activity.

This can be achieved by [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) in mysql.

Also,
[Use backticks to surround your output column_names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

```
SELECT act.event_title_column as `Event Title`, COUNT(*) as `Total Attendees`
FROM activities act
JOIN projectcode pr ON act.projects_id = pr.projects_id
JOIN participants pts ON pts.act_id = act.id
WHERE act.projects_id = '1001'
GROUP BY act.id
ORDER BY YEAR(act.activity_date) DESC;
```